# AWS / Heptio Authenticator from an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, kubernetes, amazon-iam, kubectl

So I've followed the AWS article [Deploying the Heptio Authenticator to kops](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/deploying-heptio-authenticator-kops/), and I was able to successfully able to get things running. From my laptop, which has a fully configured AWSCLI setup, I can run any `kubectl` command since I'm an administrator. The token is obtained by using the following command in my `~/.kube/config` file:

```
users:
- name: mycluster-exec
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - token
      - --cluster-id
      - mycluster
      - --role
      - arn:aws:iam::<account-number>:role/KubernetesAdministrator
      command: aws-iam-authenticator
      env: null
```

Now what I'd like to do is essentially described in the GitHub issue [EKS heptio authentication using IAM without AWSCLI](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-iam-authenticator/issues/89). I'm not using EKS, but the principle is the same. I have EC2 instances that are running my CI system's build agents, and I would like those build agents to **NOT** have static, hard-coded credentials (i.e. a static AWS ID and Secret Key). I'd prefer those nodes to also use the `aws-iam-authenticator` binary to temporarily grab credentials as needed to deploy / make changes to my Kubernetes clusters.

I created a Role / Instance profile called `KubernetesCIRole`, and attached that IAM role to my EC2 build agent nodes. I then added the following to the `ConfigMap`:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config.yaml: |
    clusterID: mycluster
    server:
      mapRoles:
      - roleARN: arn:aws:iam::<account-number>:role/KubernetesAdministrator
        username: kubernetes-admin
        groups:
        - system:masters
      - roleARN: arn:aws:iam::<account-number>:role/KubernetesCIRole
        username: kubernetes-admin
        groups:
        - system:masters
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: heptio-authenticator-aws
  name: heptio-authenticator-aws
  namespace: kube-system
```

However, when I configure the `~/.kube/config` on that EC2 build agent machine, and then run something simple like `kubectl --v=10 get pods`, I receive the following:

```
I0828 10:16:30.605964    5196 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /home/ubuntu/.kube/config
I0828 10:16:30.606744    5196 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /home/ubuntu/.kube/config
I0828 10:16:30.607704    5196 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file /home/ubuntu/.kube/config
...
I0828 10:16:33.092683    5196 round_trippers.go:386] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.11.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/bb9ffb1" 'https://api.mycluster.k8s.mycompany.com/api?timeout=32s'
I0828 10:16:33.605698    5196 round_trippers.go:405] GET https://api.mycluster.k8s.mycompany.com/api?timeout=32s 401 Unauthorized in 512 milliseconds
I0828 10:16:33.605727    5196 round_trippers.go:411] Response Headers:
I0828 10:16:33.605734    5196 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Type: application/json
I0828 10:16:33.605749    5196 round_trippers.go:414]     Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="kubernetes-master"
I0828 10:16:33.605758    5196 round_trippers.go:414]     Content-Length: 129
I0828 10:16:33.605767    5196 round_trippers.go:414]     Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 10:16:33 GMT
I0828 10:16:33.608443    5196 request.go:897] Response Body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}
I0828 10:16:33.610858    5196 cached_discovery.go:111] skipped caching discovery info due to Unauthorized
F0828 10:16:33.610901    5196 helpers.go:119] error: the server doesn't have a resource type "pods"
```

Why doesn't this work? If I've specified in the Heptio / AWS IAM Authenticator `ConfigMap` that a given role has cluster administrator access (or anything else, for that matter), shouldn't I be able to authenticate?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The AWS documentation [Managing Users or IAM Roles for your Cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) has the part that's needed:

First, you need to create an IAM role (and corresponding instance profile) which has the following basic permissions, and attach it to your EC2 instance:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you need to update the `ConfigMap` with something like the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - rolearn: <ARN of instance role (not instance profile)>
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
      groups:
        - system:masters
```

The key part is the username `system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}`. I guess the `{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}` serves as a placeholder for any EC2 instance with the corresponding `rolearn` attached to it.